# Session hijacking

Tags: android, security, network-programming

I have developed android application which communicates with server for data over HTTPS protocol. Server has self signed certificate , which is installed on the android device. once the user login to the android app , the credentials will be sent to server and authenticated then server sends a session id, which is used android app in further requests to maintain session. If somehow I hijack the session id , Is it possible to hijack the session ?? Any tools which can be used to spoof the https requests and inject the hijacked session id and sent to server to hijack session? Please help

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rohit .. As of I know Progaurd is used for shrinking , optimize and obfuscate the java classes . Can that be used for session hijacking ?

Comment: I am looking for the utility which can build the HTTP requests that spoofs the request from the android application ..

Comment: do support your question with your research you've done so far. see [ask]